# Example of reading and writing transoforms with PubSub using apache beam python sdk

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I see examples here https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io#reading-with-pubsubio  for Java, but when I look here https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.py its says:

```
def reader(self):
    raise NotImplementedError(
        'PubSubSource is not supported in local execution.')
```

What does that mean? Cloud Data Flow Python SDK PubSub Source/Sink is not quite ready?

Answer (score 1):

It means that reading from PubSub is currently not supported when executing the pipeline *locally* (on your machine, i.e. not in the cloud). Local execution is mainly used for testing.

PubSub is supported when you run using the Dataflow runner.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that it's not ready yet, as I was able to run it locally with the Java SDK and using the pubsub emulator, but as you've encountered, not with the Python SDK.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone visiting this question in 2019, I can confirm that PubSub does work with DirectRunner as long as proper Google Cloud authentication is provided.